# Find out the my recent use branches in git

Tags: git

Is there a way to find out what are the last 5 branches that I most recently used (i.e. git checkout -b )?
I am looking for a commit that I did, but I forget which branch I check that commit into.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `git reflog`. It will show you everything you have done lately.

Answer (score 1):

To show all logs from all branches, you could add a `--all` flag to git log

```
git log --all
```

If you know the message you used in the commit you could add a `--grep` with a word you used

```
git log --all --grep blah
```

If you know what file the commit touched, you could add that file after a `--` separator

```
git log --all -- /path/to/file
```

All these methods will list the commits that matches them, should be easy to find the commit if it's recent, if the commit became dangling ( not currently inside any branch ) you'll need to use either `git-reflog` or `git-fsck`

Answer (score 0):

You can filter commits by a specific committer through `git-log`:

```
git log --graph --oneline --author="<your Git name here>" --decorate --all
```

I personally use `--oneline --decorate` so that I can:

- see which branch it's on
- only see the SHA

I mention this solution because you're less concerned with the last five branches you worked on, and you're more concerned with the actual branch you made that commit on.